# Rearrangement of Complex Sin and Cos

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

From my complex numbers course notes, there is the following derivation:

[image: notes]

The definitions of sin and cos I'm very comfortable with, but I cannot see how we get from the definition to the given rearrangement. (Perhaps I'm being silly.)

Comment: Typo. It ought to be $$(1+i) \exp (-iz) = (1-i)\exp (iz).$$

Comment: Multiply the two sides by $2i$ and then re-arrange.

Comment: @DanielFischer You, sir, are correct.

Comment: And it's blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac12(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})=\frac1{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})\\ie^{iz}+ie^{-iz}=e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\\e^{-iz}(1+i)=e^{iz}(1-i)$$